# What does the 'EE' in 'Quantum GISEE' mean?

Tags: qgis

I'm doing some research on QGIS history and found in the German wikipedia article the term 'Quantum GISEE' (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS) but not in the English wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGIS). I fairly remember 'Quantum GIS' but not 'Quantum GISEE'.

Can somebody clarify this? Or is this just a typo?

Comment: Hm that's likely a typo. I don't remember any specific German name either, back when it was called *Quantum GIS*. And e.g. *EE* -> *Enterprise Edition* was even more unlikely in those days...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my question was about a typo in the german wikipedia article about QGIS meanwhile corrected by the author.

Comment: Very tidy. You should get a badge for that ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typo which did not exist in prior versions of the Wiki article. the version of november 2019  still shows the proper name: https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=QGIS&oldid=193986890

See https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog200/#feature-quantum-gis-is-now-known-only-as-qgis

Comment: I daresay, I wonder a little bit why this should be a typo, a type is something like QGSI to me, I find it very unlikely that someone adds 'EE' by incident. I'll try to find out the user and ask what is intented by this (I'm not very experienced in wikipedia, I must say...)

Comment: Maybe it's a German-specific abbreviation, or even a typo that would be more likely in German than in English. If you're really curious you could ask on [german.se].

Comment: Version history indicates, that adding 'EE' to 'Quantum-GIS' was quite intentional, I added a section to the QGIS articles discussion page (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:QGIS#Quantum-GISEE), I am very much looking forward to an answer from the author...

Comment: @JochenSchwarze: where did you find an indication that the 'EE' was added intentionally? PS: I fixed the typo in the wiki page

Comment: @markgraeflerland: where did you find an indication that the 'EE' was *not* added intentionally? Are you the the author? IMHO moving the cursor behind the GIS and typing the 'EE' is very unlikely to happen by incidence. So I adovcate waiting for what the author says. Thus I undid your changein the article.

Comment: @JochenSchwarze: because the only two official terms for QGIS were 'Quantum GIS' and 'QGIS'. the article is not about forks of QGIS like QGIS Enterprise ( qgisenterprise.com)

Comment: It was a typo. The author has corrected it.